# OpenGL ES context on asus tinker board surface failes

Tags: c++, opengl-es, arm

I am using an Asus Tinkerboard with the Tinker OS (20170417-tinker-board-linaro-stretch-alip-v1.8.iso) and am trying to open an OpenGL ES 2 context on the board in my C++ app

I have found the mali graphics SDK which contained many examples and incorporated them into my application. Unfortunately my application always fails when calling `eglCreateWindowSurface`.

Here is an image of the graphics debugger with the API trace:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIIFT.png

And the call to `eglCreateWindowSurface`:

```
eglCreateWindowSurface
(
    dpy = 0x7f6569f0, 
    config = 0x7f686160, 
    win = 0x7f651194, 
    attrib_list = NULL
)
```

The attributes chosen for the config are:

```
attrib_list = 
[
    EGL_SAMPLES, 
    4, 
    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, 
    EGL_WINDOW_BIT, 
    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 
    16, 
    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 
    8, 
    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 
    EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, 
    EGL_STENCIL_SIZE, 
    0, 
    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 
    0, 
    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 
    8, 
    EGL_BUFFER_SIZE, 
    32, 
    EGL_RED_SIZE, 
    8, 
    EGL_NONE
]
```

The context is created with:

```
attrib_list = 
[
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 
    2, 
    EGL_NONE
]
```

(I have also tried several combinations with 0 depth, no samples, etc, all result in a `EGL_BAD_ALLOC`)

The `native window` is like this:

```
typedef struct fbdev_window {
    unsigned short width;
    unsigned short height;
} fbdev_window;
```

With `width` being 700 and `height` being 480 in this context.

I tried using a different display (1st was my 4k TV, 2nd was my full hd monitor) but the same error happens on both devices. I also tried restarting it several times to make sure no surface or so was already created or out of memory, but nothing helped.

Comment: I have been reverse engineering and debugging the `libmali-midgard-r9p0-r0p0.so` library that is linked by libEGL.so. I was able to figure out that it does an `xcb_dri2_create_drawable_checked` which fails with the error `BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)`. Sadly enough the libmali library does an XGetErrorText but never actually uses that local stack variable for output... But at least now I am one step further, I need to figure out why `xcb_dri2_create_drawable_checked` fails.